# How can I create list comprehension with multiple dictionary items?

Tags: python

I am trying to create multiple lists from a dictionary. For example:

```
dict_ = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}
list_1 = [k for k, v in dict_.items()]
list_2 = [v for k, v in dict_.items()]
```

The above works but I am trying to find out if there is a single liner that would create both list_1 and list_2 instead of repeating the same "for" loop twice?

Comment: You can do `list_1 = list(dict_.keys())`, `list_2 = list(dict_.values())`. Alternatively `list_1 = list(dict_)`

Comment: If you really want a one-liner, you can of course use `list_1, list_2 = .... , ....` but I'm not sure whether that improves the code.

Comment: If you want to use the same loop (which is good), why you feel like you need it to be in one line? What's wrong with a regular `for` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You could try something with [multiple assignment](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-multi-variables-values/) if you really wanted to:

```py
list_1, list_2 = list(dict_.keys()), list(dict_.values())
```

- or you could use a single listcomp

```py
list_1, list_2 = [list(tup) for tup in zip(*dict_.items())]
```

- or if you're feeling [functional](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html) you could try

```py
list_1, list_2 = map(list, zip(*dict_.items()))
```

but [*readability counts*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) and [*simple is better than complex*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) so the two separate lines are probably a better approach

Comment: In all honesty I'd write it in two separate lines (as I mentioned in comments below the question), but I guess the OP wants a one-liner...

Comment: Thanks for the edit...

Comment: I'm giving OP what they asked but I would personally keep it as two separate lines as well lol

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

```
dict_ = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}
list_1, list_2 = list(dict_.keys()), list(dict_.values())
```